# Updating cookie values

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I have a shopping cart using cookies, you can add products to it by going to the product-detail page and click on add cart. The script needs to add +1 to the quantity in the shopping cart, everytime you can click on add. I don't know why, but the quantity stays 1 everytime.

Basically, the question is: Why doesn't it update the quantity within the cookie?

Product.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['m'])){

        if (isset($_COOKIE['cart'])){
            $cart = json_decode($_COOKIE['cart'], TRUE, 512, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY); // if cookie is set, get the contents of it
        } else{
            $cart = [];// else create an empty cart
        }    

        // append new product and add to cart
        $cart[$product['id']] = [];
        $cart[$product['id']]['m'] = empty($_POST['m']) ? 1 : $_POST['m'];
        if(!empty($cart[$product['id']]['quantity'])){
            $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] += 1;
        } else {
            $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] = 1;
        }

        setcookie('cart', json_encode($cart), time()+3600, '/');
    } else {
        $error = "U moet minimaal 1m invullen";
    }

}
```

Also in the shopping cart itself, i need to be able to modify the quantity, this value is allowed to be overwritten.

shoppingcart.php:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cart'])){
    $cart = json_decode($_COOKIE['cart'], TRUE, 512, JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
} else {
    $cart = [];
}
// dd($cart);

if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
    unset($cart[$_POST['item']]);
    setcookie('cart', json_encode($cart), time()+3600, '/');
}

$list = $model->selectMultipleById($cart, 'carpet');
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Why the quantity will be overwritten instead of updated

Comment: Because everytime you start with a new array? `$cart[$product['id']] = [];
`. So `$cart[$product['id']]['quantity']` never exists.

Comment: And on a sidenote: why are you sending information to the server every button click? You know javascript can add and modify cookies as well?

Comment: I don't work with javascript that much. Do you mean that i first need to check if the `$cart[$product['id']]` already exist, and then update the quantity within that if statement?

Comment: Yes. Now you reset `$cart[$product['id']]` to an empty array every time, so you are actualy destroing the order you had in your cookie, if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// append new product and add to cart

//first test if you have the id in your cookie. if so: update qty +1
if(!empty($cart[$product['id']])){
    $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] += 1;
} 
//else create a new item in the cookie
else {
    $cart[$product['id']] = [];
    $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] = 1;
}
//now $cart[$product['id']]['m'] always exists, so you can update m
$cart[$product['id']]['m'] = empty($_POST['m']) ? 1 : $_POST['m'];
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried something aswell, It worked too but seems to be too much code for what needed to be done

Comment: And still, imho you should look into javascript cookies. it saves you a roundtrip to the server every button click.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i tried but i seem to repeat myself with my code.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cart'][$product['id']])){
                $cart[$product['id']]['m'] = empty($_POST['m']) ? 1 : $_POST['m'];
                if(!empty($cart[$product['id']]['quantity'])){
                    $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] += 1;
                } else {
                    $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                $cart[$product['id']] = [];
                $cart[$product['id']]['m'] = empty($_POST['m']) ? 1 : $_POST['m'];
                $cart[$product['id']]['quantity'] = 1;
            }
```